# TFS 2010 API - After workspace.Merge() status is NoActionNeeded

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I wrote a little tool to programmatically merge multiple branches. I use the following code:

```
    var candidates = _server.GetMergeCandidates(sourcePath, targetPath, RecursionType.Full);
    foreach (var c in candidates)
    {
        var changeset = new ChangesetVersionSpec(c.Changeset.ChangesetId);
        var status = _workspace.Merge(sourcePath, targetPath, changeset, changeset);
        if (!status.NoActionNeeded)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I get the correct merge candidates, but the status on each one is NoActionNeeded. When, I merge manually the changes show up as pending changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one of my own tools I do a very similar action with:

```
_workspace.Merge(sourcePath, targetPath, null, null, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptionsEx.None)
```

This operates on the 'latest' stand.

Comment: check also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396738/tfs-sdk-merge-doesnt-work